# ASCII art renders differently on Android devices?

Tags: android, utf-8, fonts, pre, ascii-art

Having a little issue with the rendering of some ASCII art on Android devices, i have a site up here https://crowdesk.org/android/basictest.html , If you view this site on a Desktop or iOS device it renders normally As you can see

[image: well rendered ASCII]

However when i view the website on Android devices, (Have tried Android Chrome and Samsung internet) it renders much differently. My intuition is telling me this is a Android specific font rendering quirk, perhaps to do with the rendering of Unicode Block elements? Although i think it also could have something to do the handling of monospaced fonts.

[image]

As far as the code goes i'm using the pre tags which indicate preformatted text, please also note, this issue does not seem to be impacted by screen size, rather i have only been able to emulate the issue when viewing from an actual Android device.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" charset="utf-8">
<pre>
  +--------------------------------------+
  |                                      |
  |                     ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄     |
  |    Idena            █  ▀▄▄▄▄▀  █     |
  |                  ▄▀ █ ▄▄    ▄▄▄▀ ▌▄  |
  |                  ▀  ▌▓▄▄▌▌▐▐▒▄▓▐ ▌▀  |
  |                 ▐   █    ▌▐    █ ▌▀▌ |
  |                  ▓  █    ▄▄    █ ▌▓  |
  |                  ▀█ ▌▌▄ ▀▓▓▀  ▓▐ █▀  |
  |                     ▌▌▌▌▄  ▄▓▀▐▐     |
  |                       ▀▀▄▄▄▄ ▀       |
  |                                      |
  +--------------------------------------+
</pre>
</html>
```

Comment: It could be just a font problem. Not all "fix width" fonts are really fix width on all glyphs. It is much better to specify the font, or just to use ASCII characters for ASCII-art (not just the purest form of ASCII art, but also with less problems about font).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own issue by following up from the comment from Giacomo Catenazzi, basically i downloaded a copy of Courier put that on my webserver, then forced pre to use that version of Courier using the font face specification. Working now :)

```html
pre {
    font-family: Courier;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Courier;
  src: url(Courier.ttf);
}
```